# Why isn't Angular loading my partials?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that loads pages using partials. However, sometimes those partials don't load. I was able to capture one in Fiddler and it seems that the status returned is 206 ("partial content" using a byte range). For some reason the request has a Range header:

```
GET http://brian:90/Offices/Details/Details.html HTTP/1.1
Host: brian:90
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://brian:90/Office/18207
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: XXX
Range: bytes=3695-3695
If-Range: "80f21e2992acf1:0"
```

And here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sat, 15 Feb 2014 04:48:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "80f21e2992acf1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Glimpse-RequestID: 7b58956c-2917-457c-b47d-d602fb304d59
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 15 Feb 2014 04:54:16 GMT
Content-Length: 1
Content-Range: bytes 3695-3695/4135

?
```

Here is the route config...

```
officeApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/summary', {
            title: 'Summary',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Summary/Summary.html',
            controller: 'summaryCtrl'
        })
        .when('/reports', {
            Title: 'Reports',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Reports/Reports.html',
            controller: 'reportsCtrl'
        })
        .when('/details', {
            Title: 'Details',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Details/Details.html',
            controller: 'detailsCtrl'
        })
        .when('/logos', {
            Title: 'Logos',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Logos/Logos.html?v=2',
            controller: 'logosCtrl'
        })
        .when('/agents', {
            Title: 'Agents',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Agents/Agents.html',
            controller: 'agentsCtrl'
        })
        .when('/theme', {
            Title: 'Tour Theme',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Theme/Theme.html',
            controller: 'themeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/packages', {
            Title: 'Packages',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Packages/Packages.html',
            controller: 'packagesCtrl'
        })
        .when('/admin', {
            Title: 'CS Admin',
            templateUrl: '/Offices/Admin/Admin.html',
            controller: 'adminCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/summary' });
}]);
```

Any idea what's happening? Why is Angular requesting a byte range of only a single byte?

Comment: Can you show your angular route config (assuming you are using ngRoute)?

Comment: What do you mean by *sometimes*?

Comment: @link64, I updated with the route config. It is super basic.

Comment: @MattWay, sometimes it loads, and then it stops working. I then have to go into the html file for the partial and make a change (anything to change the ETag).

Comment: hard refresh each time you make a change? I find it helps when I'm working with Angular.

Comment: @adamS, hard refresh doesn't seem to help since the partials are loaded through Angular. I have had luck by clearing the cache, but that is a few steps too many for as often as this happens. For whatever reason, the templates go bad all on their own, without me making any changes to them.

Comment: @Brian Are you using Chrome? If yes, uncheck `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` in the developer tool.

Comment: @zsong, Thanks. I was sure I checked that before, but it was unchecked when I looked.

Comment: The problem might not be Angular or Chrome. I found another issue that might be related (perhaps one occurs first then the other one happens?). Anyway, it seems that IIS is, at least in some cases, messing up the compression. If I reset IIS, it starts working again.